# Couch DB running on Windows OS is paging while it has ample RAM available

Tags: memory, erlang, couchdb, paging, ram

I have three node CouchDB cluster. It is running on windows. Each node has 16vcpu and 64GB RAM. I am fairly new to CouchDB and to nonrelational databases in general.
The cluster is running on windows. What I am struggling with is one of the nodes (which I am assuming is the coordinator) is using the page file about 120GB disk space while it has about 48GB free RAM available to it.
We increased the RAM from 32Gb to 64GB to help with the paging. Only to find out that, it is now using more of the page file since the page file is being currently managed by the Windows OS.
I would assume it would be paging once it used all the available RAM, but what we have is 120GB paging file while it has about 50GB free RAM.
Why is it using the page file which has less response time while it has free RAM available to it?
Wasn't it supposed to use unreserved RAM for disk caching of frequently accessed DB file blocks to speed up access? Why is it behaving this way?
Is there a CouchDB or Erlang Beam configuration setting that I should be looking at?